# How to make a preference bundle for my mobile substrate tweak?

Tags: ios, settings, tweak, theos, cydia-substrate

I have `theos`, `sdk3` installed in my iPhone

I have created a working tweak too but have no idea how to create a preference bundle to add some settings.

I want A Yes/No or a BOOL button to be added into the preference button to see if the tweak wants to be enabled or not

How do i make my tweak to read if it is enabled or not?
Exmaple:

```
-(void)Something {
    if (Enable = YES) {
        /*Method here*/ }
    else {
        //Do nothing
         }
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Try to check this link http://blog.aehmlo.com/2012/08/03/new-tweak-readme/
Aehmlo Lxaitn explains in details how to make a simple tweak and add a settings to enable/disable it.

It works for me.
Hope it's what you need.

You may also want to install "Theos Tutorials" from Cydia. It's author is ReverseEffect.

Anothe tutorial from http://shahiddev.blogspot.com/2011/11/mobilesubstrate-tweak-tutorial-with.html

go to "Settings"

```
What about if the user would like to disable our tweak? We can give him the
ability to enable or disable it from a preference bundle.
(We could use just a plist for something simple like this, but we’ll use a
preference bundle project in order to try it out).  I’m going to skip a few
steps with this, since you can figure them out yourself, looking at the
source code you can download below.

 - Launch the new instance creator, and initiate a “PreferenceBundle” project. 
 - Add that project as a “subproject” in your main tweak project, by
   adding the SUBPROJECTS = tutorialsettings key in the Makefile.
 - The structure of the preference bundle is given by a plist containing
   a collection os PSSpecifiers, used by the standard Preferences app.
 - Create a switch controlling the “Enabled” key.
 - For its “defaults” key set it to the package id you used before
   (com.filippobiga.tutorial). This means it’ll write to a plist with
   that name in the Preferences folder of the user.
 - Now you need to modify the code in the Tweak.xm to read the user’s
   Settings and determine if it should flash the screen or not.

That’s it!
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will view it now. I have theos tutorials set up but his tutorial on tweaks for preference bundles is not working for me

Comment: Why am I not able to open that page in my iPhone?

Comment: Have no idea why. Try from computer.

Comment: have you opened the first link on your computer?